# Firing a tag on certain pages in Google Tag Manager

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to create a regexp to fire a tag within Google Tag Manager on certain pages.

The issue I am having is that I do not want to fire this tag on URLs matching a querystring in them, since it is only a session identifier and I do not need the tag to fire on the pages that have a query string. These are basically duplicates and they do not need tracking in a 3rd party tracking program. I know how I could exclude them in GA, but I can't figure out how to do it for the third party tracking.

I'll detail the scenario below and what I have tried.

Example pages that come up in my URL report if I look in GA:

> /page
>
> /page/subpage?my-handsome-query-string&some-other-data
>
> /page/subpage
>
> /page/subpage/subsubpage
>
> /page/?query-string-again

So what I want to do is to fire the tracking on pages that does NOT have the query string, and it is proving quite the issue.

If I put in `^/page.*[^\?]` it just doesn't work. I guess I am completely using the negated character class all wrong? I can't get it working and would require some assistance on how to devise a better regexp.

Some other I tried were:

`^/page/.*` but this one only matched everything after `/page/` but not `/page`.

I am not very good with regular expressions, so what I basically want to do is match `/page, /page/subpage, /page/subpage/subpage` etc, but not any URL that has a query string in it.

In GTM I can't create two rules that says `"Include {{url path}} matching this" and "Exclude {{url path}} matching \?"`, so it all needs to be done within one regexp... And that totally got me at a loss.

Edit: Mike gave a good answer to solve my GTM part, but I am still interested in learning if it is possible to do above but with a single regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually create two rules as you described.

In GTM, tags can have both Firing rules and Blocking rules. Blocking takes precedence. eg.

Firing rule:

```
{{url}} matches ^page/.*
```

Blocking rule:

```
{{url}} does not contain ?
```

Another option is to use a custom javascript macro.
It is in the form of a `function(){ }` which can detect a query string value in `window.location.search` and return boolean. Then have a firing rule `{{your custom fn}} equals 1`.

You can also create a macro which uses the `URL` macro type and `Query` component type.
The value is set to the query string without the leading `?`. If the url was `example.com?foo=bar` this macro would contain `foo=bar`. Then simply add a firing rule `{{query}} matches Regex ^$` or `{{query}} does not contain something-that-will-never-be-in-the-url-to-avoid-regex`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mike. This does indeed solve my GTM issue. It would be great though if anyone had some input regarding my regex issue, because I would still like to know if it is possible to do above with one single regex.

Comment: Sounds like the regex you're after is `^\/page[^\?]*?$`

Comment: Which means urls starting with (^) /pages followed by anything that is not a "?" zero or more times (*?) up until the end of the string ($)

Comment: Thank you. I will give them a swirl!

Comment: Why use a complex regex when you can create 2 simple rules? The solution in the answer is more elegant.

Comment: 2 rules is a lot more maintainable too. Come back in 3 months and you'll have to decipher the regex.